# MySQL & php PDO how to fetch: SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE y = :value)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm using this syntax instead of count (*) because it's supposed to be faster but I dont know how to fetch the resulting output

```
$alreadyMember = $dataBase->prepare('SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
FROM TheCommunityReachLinkingTable 
WHERE communityKey = :communityKey 
AND userID = :userID)');
$alreadyMember->bindParam(':communityKey', $_POST['communityKey'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$alreadyMember->bindParam(':userID', $_POST['userID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$alreadyMember->execute();

if($alreadyMember->fetch()) {do code here}
```

But it doesn't seems to return something correct, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `EXISTS` seems wrong here. Just execute this query instead:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM TheCommunityReachLinkingTable 
WHERE communityKey = :communityKey 
AND userID = :userID
```

Comment: Should I set LIMIT 1 at the end?

Comment: @NicolasManzini only if you know there will be cases in which multiple records are returned for any `communityKey` and `userID` combination.

Answer (score 0):

The proper usage is just like normal, capture the return value of fetch()

```
$row = $alreadyMember->fetch();
print_r($row); // you may have numeric or string indices depending on the FETCH_MODE you set, pick one, consider a column alias and associative


//or the easy way
$alreadyMember->execute();
if ($alreadyMember-fetchColumn()) {
    //column 0 contained a truthy value
}
```